# Add hours and minutes to a Date object

Tags: java, date, javafx, datepicker

I have a small gui which have a datepicker and a textbox where I enter a time (HH:mm).

I want to create a method whish takes the Date from the datepicker and adds the time (HH:mm) to the datepicker-date and then returns the Date so I can save it in a database.

I want to have the final date in this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

This is what I have tried:

```
public Date getCalibrationDate(){
        String time = getTime();
        int hours = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(0,2));
        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(time.substring(2,4));
        Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(kalibreringsdatum.getValue());

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minutes);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        String dateAsString = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        Date dateTime = null;

        try {
            dateTime = sdf.parse(dateAsString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not parse date");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dateTime;
    }
```

But it returns the date in this way: Tue Dec 11 11:22:00 CET 2018.
What am I doing wrong and how can I simplify the method?

Comment: Are you using java 8?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: Use the `java.time` API - much easier solution

Comment: Not sure why you would use `String dateAsString = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());` followed by `dateTime = sdf.parse(dateAsString);` is `Calendar#getTime` returns an instance of `java.util.Date`

Comment: Unless there's some very specific reason, avoid using `java.sql.Date`, prefer `java.util.Date` - better yet, use `java.time.LocalDateTime`

Comment: Why are you converting the `Date` to a formatted `String`, then back into a `Date` again? You're doing the formatting into the format you want, but then you're discarding it.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Which type does `kalibreringsdatum.getValue()` return? `LocalDate`? `String`? Or something else? In any case a `Date` cannot have a format, so this is not possible: “I want to have the final date in this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"”. Fortunately it is also completely unnecessary, as [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53714934/5772882) shows.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Instead if `time` is `11:22`, I get `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ":2"`.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

For database column of type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

```
myPreparedStatement                        // As of JDBC 4.2, send/receive java.time objects to/from your database.
.setObject(                                // Call `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject` for java.time objects.
    … ,                                    // Fill-in to indicate which placeholder in SQL statement.
    LocalDateTime.of(                      // Represent a date with time-of-day, but lacking in zone/offset so NOT a moment, NOT a point on the timeline.
        LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-23" ) ,  // Parse the date-only value.
        LocalTime.parse( "21:54" )         // Parse the time-of-day.
    )                                      // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
)
```

For database column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
myPreparedStatement                        // As of JDBC 4.2, send/receive java.time objects to/from your database.
.setObject(                                // Call `PreparedStatement::setObject` and `ResultSet::getObject` for java.time objects.
    … ,                                    // Fill-in to indicate which placeholder in SQL statement.
    LocalDateTime.of(                      // Represent a date with time-of-day, but lacking in zone/offset so NOT a moment, NOT a point on the timeline.
        LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-23" ) ,  // Parse the date-only value.
        LocalTime.parse( "21:54" )         // Parse the time-of-day.
    )                                      // Returns a `LocalDateTime` object.
    .atZone(                               // Assign a time zone to make a moment.
        ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )    // Real time zones have a proper name in `Continent/Region` format. Never use 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `PDT`, `IST`, `CST`, etc. 
    )                                      // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    .toOffsetDateTime()                    // Strip out the time zone, leaving only a mere offset-from-UTC (a number of hours-minutes-seconds). Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object.
    .withOffsetSameInstant(                // Adjust the offset-from-UTC to UTC itself (an offset of zero). Same moment, different wall-clock time.
        ZoneOffset.UTC 
    )                                      // Returns another `OffsetDateTime` object.
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible old legacy classes (`Calendar`, `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.).

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

The common SQL format for a date-only value in text is YYYY-MM-DD. This is also the format defined by the ISO 8601 standard. The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-23" ) ;
```

Similar for a string in format of HH:MM for hours and minutes of a time-of-day.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "21:54" ) ;
```

Combine the date with the time.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-01-23T21:54

Be aware that a `LocalDateTime`, purposely lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, is *not* a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. As such, it is only appropriate to save to a database in a column of a data type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

### JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database via `setObject` & `getObject`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to work with moments, actual points on the timeline, use the appropriate Java classes (`Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

### `OffsetDateTime`

Now we have a moment at hand. Usually best to focus on UTC when moving dates around such as transferring to a database.

```
OffsetDateTime odtUtc = zdt.toOffsetDateTime().withOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Send to database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odtUtc ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to get what you want:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateAndTime {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()))
}
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: You can, but as others have said, you shouldn’t in 2018. And your code will not always give the expected result.

Comment: Basil Bourque, thank you, really useful information. Will keep it in mind.